# Fragment always shows loading icon

Tags: android, android-fragments, actionbarsherlock, fragment

[image]

My android fragment contain list.
This list work fine but loading icon always moving.
here is my source code

```
@Override
public void onDataPass(String data) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Log.e("INterface","Interfacxe data"+data);
    Log.e("onTextChanged",data);
    List<Contact> contacts = db.get_data(data);  
    int i=0;

    String[] ss=null;
    ss=new String[contacts.size()];




    for (Contact cn : contacts) {

        Log.e("Value","value"+cn.get_name1());
        ss[i]=cn.get_id();
        Log.e("DATTA","value"+ss[i]);i++;
        //  adapter.add(cn.get_id());

    }
    adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity()
            .getApplicationContext(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,
            android.R.id.text1,ss);

    // Assign adapter to ListView
    listView.setAdapter(adapter);


    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();


}
```

loading icon always stay there ,how to remove that icon

Comment: can you please upload some code

Comment: @Datta provide your mainactivity and fragment code